# How can I use Address Proximity as a search critieria in FormBuilder?

Tags: formbuilder

Is it possible to build a search form in FormBuilder that allows for Address Proximity search? If so, what am I missing to make it work?

When building a search form with FormBuilder, I see that "Address Proximity" is available as a field to be added to the form. However, I can't seem to make it work as an actual search criteria. Here's what I'm doing:

First I add the field to the form in the builder:
[image: Form builder: insert the field]

It's odd that it appears as a label with no field, and perhaps more odd that the settings for this field show a blank value for Type:
[image]

(I've tried specifying each of the various Type options, such as Select, Checkbox, etc., but none of them result in form fields that would be useful for proximity searching.)

I save that form and open the page, and still I see just the label with no field (or else some useless-in-this-context field such as a yes/no select, etc., depending on the Type option I manually specified):
[image]

For what it's worth, I have verified that geocoding (via Google) is working fine on this site.

Comment: What is the base table for your search? I haven't tested but it's possible the base table needs to be address, and then you can join in other things.

Comment: @Demerit Base table is Contact (with Address joined if primary) in the example above, but I just tried now and the behavior is the same when base table is Address (with or without Contact joined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proximity filter uses a specialized field type which hadn't been defined in Afform.

I've posted a Pull-Request to fix this: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27631 (should be included in the CiviCRM 5.67 release).